# Exception initializing level

Tags: java, initialization, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

Hey im playing minecraft with a own created modpack i made on curseforge but im getting the following error/crash when i create a world.

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Uh... Did I do that?

Time: 5/5/21 2:23 PM
Description: Exception initializing level

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at dev.onyxstudios.cca.internal.entity.CardinalEntityInternals.lambda$createEntityComponentContainer$3(CardinalEntityInternals.java:101)
    at dev.onyxstudios.cca.internal.entity.CardinalEntityInternals$$Lambda$7701/880609584.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1118)
    at dev.onyxstudios.cca.internal.entity.CardinalEntityInternals.createEntityComponentContainer(CardinalEntityInternals.java:86)
    at net.minecraft.class_1297.handler$bjg001$initDataTracker(class_1297.java:8685)
    at net.minecraft.class_1297.<init>(class_1297.java:263)
    at net.minecraft.class_1309.<init>(class_1309.java:219)
    at net.minecraft.class_1308.<init>(class_1308.java:125)
    at net.minecraft.class_1314.<init>(class_1314.java:12)
    at net.minecraft.class_1296.<init>(class_1296.java:28)
    at net.minecraft.class_1429.<init>(class_1429.java:39)
    at net.minecraft.class_1430.<init>(class_1430.java:35)
    at net.minecraft.class_1299$$Lambda$1110/847653000.create(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.class_1299.method_5883(class_1299.java:463)
    at net.minecraft.class_1948.method_8661(class_1948.java:499)
    at net.minecraft.class_3754.method_12107(class_3754.java:760)
    at net.minecraft.class_2806.method_16566(class_2806.java:107)
    at net.minecraft.class_2806$$Lambda$1958/1442570492.doWork(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.class_2806$class_3768.doWork(class_2806.java:263)
    at net.minecraft.class_2806.method_12154(class_2806.java:219)
    at net.minecraft.class_3898.method_17225(class_3898.java:568)
    at net.minecraft.class_3898$$Lambda$7401/198104452.apply(Unknown Source)
    at com.mojang.datafixers.util.Either$Left.map(Either.java:38)
    at net.minecraft.class_3898.method_17224(class_3898.java:562)
    at net.minecraft.class_3898$$Lambda$7386/1828216218.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:952)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:926)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:442)
    at net.minecraft.class_3900.method_17634(class_3900.java:58)
    at net.minecraft.class_3900$$Lambda$7399/1437892875.run(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.class_3846.method_16907(class_3846.java:94)
    at net.minecraft.class_3846.method_16900(class_3846.java:137)
    at net.minecraft.class_3846.run(class_3846.java:105)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1689)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to hack fabric API
    at dev.onyxstudios.cca.internal.base.ComponentsInternals.<clinit>(ComponentsInternals.java:56)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: type
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2070)
    at dev.onyxstudios.cca.internal.base.ComponentsInternals.<clinit>(ComponentsInternals.java:52)
    ... 38 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Server thread
Stacktrace:
    at dev.onyxstudios.cca.internal.entity.CardinalEntityInternals.lambda$createEntityComponentContainer$3(CardinalEntityInternals.java:101)
    at dev.onyxstudios.cca.internal.entity.CardinalEntityInternals$$Lambda$7701/880609584.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1118)
    at dev.onyxstudios.cca.internal.entity.CardinalEntityInternals.createEntityComponentContainer(CardinalEntityInternals.java:86)
    at net.minecraft.class_1297.handler$bjg001$initDataTracker(class_1297.java:8685)
    at net.minecraft.class_1297.<init>(class_1297.java:263)
    at net.minecraft.class_1309.<init>(class_1309.java:219)
    at net.minecraft.class_1308.<init>(class_1308.java:125)
    at net.minecraft.class_1314.<init>(class_1314.java:12)
    at net.minecraft.class_1296.<init>(class_1296.java:28)
    at net.minecraft.class_1429.<init>(class_1429.java:39)
    at net.minecraft.class_1430.<init>(class_1430.java:35)
    at net.minecraft.class_1299$$Lambda$1110/847653000.create(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.class_1299.method_5883(class_1299.java:463)
    at net.minecraft.class_1948.method_8661(class_1948.java:499)
    at net.minecraft.class_3754.method_12107(class_3754.java:760)
    at net.minecraft.class_2806.method_16566(class_2806.java:107)
    at net.minecraft.class_2806$$Lambda$1958/1442570492.doWork(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.class_2806$class_3768.doWork(class_2806.java:263)
    at net.minecraft.class_2806.method_12154(class_2806.java:219)
    at net.minecraft.class_3898.method_17225(class_3898.java:568)
    at net.minecraft.class_3898$$Lambda$7401/198104452.apply(Unknown Source)
    at com.mojang.datafixers.util.Either$Left.map(Either.java:38)
    at net.minecraft.class_3898.method_17224(class_3898.java:562)
    at net.minecraft.class_3898$$Lambda$7386/1828216218.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:952)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:926)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:442)
    at net.minecraft.class_3900.method_17634(class_3900.java:58)
    at net.minecraft.class_3900$$Lambda$7399/1437892875.run(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.class_3846.method_16907(class_3846.java:94)

-- Affected level --
Details:
    All players: 0 total; []
    Chunk stats: ServerChunkCache: 529
    Level dimension: minecraft:overworld
    Level spawn location: World: (104,64,40), Chunk: (at 8,4,8 in 6,2; contains blocks 96,0,32 to 111,255,47), Region: (0,0; contains chunks 0,0 to 31,31, blocks 0,0,0 to 511,255,511)
    Level time: 0 game time, 0 day time
    Level name: origins and all sorts of stuff
    Level game mode: Game mode: survival (ID 0). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
    Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
    Known server brands: fabric
    Level was modded: true
    Level storage version: 0x04ABD - Anvil
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.method_3786(MinecraftServer.java:386)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.method_3735(MinecraftServer.java:335)
    at net.minecraft.class_1132.method_3823(class_1132.java:67)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.method_29741(MinecraftServer.java:645)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.method_29739(MinecraftServer.java:257)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer$$Lambda$7277/77642181.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.16.5
    Minecraft Version ID: 1.16.5
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_51, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 1323934248 bytes (1262 MB) / 2335703040 bytes (2227 MB) up to 3817865216 bytes (3641 MB)
    CPUs: 4
    JVM Flags: 5 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xss1M -Xmx4096m -Xms256m -XX:PermSize=256m
    Fabric Mods: 
        adorn: Adorn 1.13.0+1.16.5
        angerable-patch: Angerable Patch 1.1.0-1.16.4
        autoconfig1u: Auto Config v1 Updated 3.3.1
        autoconfigtoml: AutoConfig-TOML 1.0.0-fabric
        battletowers: Battle Towers 3.3.4-1.16.4
        blockus: Blockus 2.1.1+1.16.5
        blue_endless_jankson: jankson 1.2.0
        byg: BYG 1.1.7
        campanion: Campanion 1.3.5
        cardinal-components-base: Cardinal Components API (base) 2.7.9
        cardinal-components-entity: Cardinal Components API (entities) 2.7.9
        cloth-api: Cloth API 1.4.9
        cloth-armor-api-v1: Cloth Armor API v1 1.4.9
        cloth-basic-math: Cloth Basic Math 0.5.1
        cloth-client-events-v0: Cloth Client Events v0 1.4.9
        cloth-common-events-v1: Cloth Common Events v1 1.4.9
        cloth-config2: Cloth Config v4 4.11.19
        cloth-datagen-api-v1: Cloth Datagen v1 1.4.9
        cloth-durability-bar-api-v1: Cloth Durability Bar API v1 1.4.9
        cloth-dynamic-registry-api-v1: Cloth Dynamic Registry API v1 1.4.9
        cloth-scissors-api-v1: Cloth Scissors API v1 1.4.9
        cloth-utils-v1: Cloth Utils v1 1.4.9
        com_electronwill_night-config_core: core 3.6.3
        com_electronwill_night-config_toml: toml 3.6.3
        croptopia: Croptopia 1.3.5
        diggusmaximus: Diggus Maximus 1.4.2-1.16.3
        fabric: Fabric API 0.34.1+1.16
        fabric-api-base: Fabric API Base 0.3.0+c88702897d
        fabric-api-lookup-api-v1: Fabric API Lookup API (v1) 1.0.0+dc716ea17d
        fabric-biome-api-v1: Fabric Biome API (v1) 3.1.1+ca58154a7d
        fabric-blockrenderlayer-v1: Fabric BlockRenderLayer Registration (v1) 1.1.5+ca58154a7d
        fabric-command-api-v1: Fabric Command API (v1) 1.1.1+351679a77d
        fabric-commands-v0: Fabric Commands (v0) 0.2.2+ca58154a7d
        fabric-containers-v0: Fabric Containers (v0) 0.1.11+9354966b7d
        fabric-content-registries-v0: Fabric Content Registries (v0) 0.2.1+ca58154a7d
        fabric-crash-report-info-v1: Fabric Crash Report Info (v1) 0.1.3+ca58154a7d
        fabric-dimensions-v1: Fabric Dimensions API (v1) 2.0.6+61336ba97d
        fabric-entity-events-v1: Fabric Entity Events (v1) 1.1.0+c88702897d
        fabric-events-interaction-v0: Fabric Events Interaction (v0) 0.4.2+ca58154a7d
        fabric-events-lifecycle-v0: Fabric Events Lifecycle (v0) 0.2.1+ca58154a7d
        fabric-game-rule-api-v1: Fabric Game Rule API (v1) 1.0.6+ca58154a7d
        fabric-item-api-v1: Fabric Item API (v1) 1.2.1+ca58154a7d
        fabric-item-groups-v0: Fabric Item Groups (v0) 0.2.7+2868a2287d
        fabric-key-binding-api-v1: Fabric Key Binding API (v1) 1.0.4+9354966b7d
        fabric-keybindings-v0: Fabric Key Bindings (v0) 0.2.1+ca58154a7d
        fabric-language-kotlin: Fabric Language Kotlin 1.5.0+kotlin.1.4.31
        fabric-lifecycle-events-v1: Fabric Lifecycle Events (v1) 1.2.1+ca58154a7d
        fabric-loot-tables-v1: Fabric Loot Tables (v1) 1.0.2+ca58154a7d
        fabric-mining-levels-v0: Fabric Mining Levels (v0) 0.1.3+ca58154a7d
        fabric-models-v0: Fabric Models (v0) 0.3.0+bc7a746f7d
        fabric-networking-api-v1: Fabric Networking API (v1) 1.0.2+d6244c6d7d
        fabric-networking-blockentity-v0: Fabric Networking Block Entity (v0) 0.2.8+ca58154a7d
        fabric-networking-v0: Fabric Networking (v0) 0.3.2+ca58154a7d
        fabric-object-builder-api-v1: Fabric Object Builder API (v1) 1.9.5+c88702897d
        fabric-object-builders-v0: Fabric Object Builders (v0) 0.7.2+ca58154a7d
        fabric-particles-v1: Fabric Particles (v1) 0.2.4+ca58154a7d
        fabric-registry-sync-v0: Fabric Registry Sync (v0) 0.7.4+ca58154a7d
        fabric-renderer-api-v1: Fabric Renderer API (v1) 0.4.2+2868a2287d
        fabric-renderer-indigo: Fabric Renderer - Indigo 0.4.4+ca58154a7d
        fabric-renderer-registries-v1: Fabric Renderer Registries (v1) 2.3.0+2868a2287d
        fabric-rendering-data-attachment-v1: Fabric Rendering Data Attachment (v1) 0.1.5+ca58154a7d
        fabric-rendering-fluids-v1: Fabric Rendering Fluids (v1) 0.1.13+ca58154a7d
        fabric-rendering-v0: Fabric Rendering (v0) 1.1.2+ca58154a7d
        fabric-rendering-v1: Fabric Rendering (v1) 1.6.0+2868a2287d
        fabric-resource-loader-v0: Fabric Resource Loader (v0) 0.4.6+2868a2287d
        fabric-screen-api-v1: Fabric Screen API (v1) 1.0.0+c045166c7d
        fabric-screen-handler-api-v1: Fabric Screen Handler API (v1) 1.1.5+9354966b7d
        fabric-structure-api-v1: Fabric Structure API (v1) 1.1.4+ca58154a7d
        fabric-tag-extensions-v0: Fabric Tag Extensions (v0) 1.1.1+ca58154a7d
        fabric-textures-v0: Fabric Textures (v0) 1.0.6+ca58154a7d
        fabric-tool-attribute-api-v1: Fabric Tool Attribute API (v1) 1.2.7+8183d3957d
        fabricloader: Fabric Loader 0.11.3
        fallflyinglib: FallFlyingLib 1.1.0
        fiber: fiber 0.23.0-2
        identity: Identity 1.13.0-1.16.5
        imm_ptl_core: Immersive Portals Core 0.90
        immersive_portals: Immersive Portals 0.90
        inventoryhud: Inventory HUD + 3.3.0
        io_github_onyxstudios_cardinal-components-api: Cardinal-Components-API 2.7.9
        jankson: Jankson 3.0.1+j1.2.0
        java: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 8
        jumploader: Jumploader 2.1.3
        kyrptconfig: Kytpt Config 1.1.4-1.16
        libcd: LibCapableData 3.0.3+1.16.3
        libgui: LibGui 3.3.2+1.16.4
        libstructure: LibStructure 1.5
        minecraft: Minecraft 1.16.5
        modmenu: Mod Menu v1.16.8+unknown.bd9230a
        mostructures: Mo' Structures 1.1.1+mc.1.16.5
        okzoomer: Ok Zoomer 4.0.1+1.16.2
        omega-config: OmegaConfig 1.0.4
        org_jetbrains_kotlin_kotlin-reflect: kotlin-reflect 1.4.31
        org_jetbrains_kotlin_kotlin-stdlib: kotlin-stdlib 1.4.31
        org_jetbrains_kotlin_kotlin-stdlib-jdk7: kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 1.4.31
        org_jetbrains_kotlin_kotlin-stdlib-jdk8: kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 1.4.31
        org_jetbrains_kotlinx_kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm: kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm 1.4.2
        org_jetbrains_kotlinx_kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8: kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8 1.4.2
        org_jetbrains_kotlinx_kotlinx-serialization-core-jvm: kotlinx-serialization-core-jvm 1.1.0
        org_jetbrains_kotlinx_kotlinx-serialization-json-jvm: kotlinx-serialization-json-jvm 1.1.0
        origins: Origins 0.7.0
        playerabilitylib: Pal 1.2.1
        reach-entity-attributes: Reach Entity Attribute 1.0.1
        repurposed_structures: Repurposed Structures 1.16.5-1.10.5-fabric
        static-content: Static Content 1.0.2-1.16.2
        staticdata: Static Data 1.1.2
        structure-helpers: Structure Helpers 3.0.0
        tk_valoeghese_zoesteriaconfig: ZoesteriaConfig 1.3.2
        trinkets: Trinkets 2.6.7
        vanilladeathchest: VanillaDeathChest 2.0.6-fabric
        voyager: Voyager 1.0.0
        worldedit: WorldEdit 7.2.5+57d5ac9
    Player Count: 0 / 8; []
    Data Packs: vanilla (incompatible), Fabric Mods
    Type: Integrated Server (map_client.txt)
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fabric'
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

I tried:
restarting the game &
looking for incompatible mods

Mods:
Inventory HUD+,
Adorn,
Blockus,
Campanion,
CleanCut,
Cloth API(fabric),
Cloth API Config(fabric),
Croptopia(FABRIC/FORGE),
Diggus Maximus,
Draylar's battle towers,
Fabric API,
Fabric Language Kotlin,
FallingTree(Forge&Fabric),
Identity,
Immersive Portals,
Jumploader,
Mo' Structures,
Oh The Biomes You'll Go[FABRIC],
Ok Zoomer,
Origins,
Repurposed Structures(FABRIC),
ToroHealth Damage Indicators,
Trinkets,
VanillaDeathChest(fabric),
WorldEdit,
Xaero's MiniMap,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one of your plugins is using `Cardinal-Components-API`. There are two options here:

1. This `Cardinal-Components-API` contains a bug or is not compatible with your Minecraft server version.
2. Another plugin is performing bytecode manipulation causing it to become incompatible with `Cardinal-Components-API`.
   I would suggest that you start with a clean server, adding mods one by one until the issue occurs. Then when you know which mod or combination of mods causes the issue, you can look up their sourcecode and make adjustments to make them compatible with each other. If you do not know Java, then it simply means that you cannot use the combination of mods unless the authors or another programmer agrees to do this for you.

Comment: thanks the problem was that i didn't have cardinal components installed now im happily living as a human fish XD

Comment: @NielsGames25 Good to hear. If you feel like my answer has helped solving your problem, then you should mark it as accepted answer. Happy Minecrafting :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `dev.onyxstudios.cca`, whatever that might be, and it is using reflection to get at a field named `type` of some unspecified class.

It is either trying to get at the field named `type` of one of JDK's own classes, in which case **the fix is to uninstall whatever JDK you installed and install AdoptOpenJDK11: You're on a too-new version of java and these most recent versions have been breaking apps left and right by disabling aspects of the reflective API**.

Or, it is trying to get to a field named `type` in one of the classes of the FABRIC project, perhaps, whatever that might be, based on the content of this error message. In which case, the problem is a version incompatibility between these two plugins. Look up the project pages of these 2 plugins and install 2 versions whose release dates are close together. **This usually involves downgrading the more recently updated one.**